# test comman works in terminal but not in php

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-artisan

When i execute `php artisan test --testsuite=myTestsuite` in the terminal i get the right result which is just this testsuite exucuted with its tests.

But when i execute `php artisan myCommand`:
[image: commandFile]

Then the testsuite which is listed first in the phpunit.xml is executed first and then the one which i passed the name.

Has somebody an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please do not post images of code, but add the code in a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it with

```
shell_exec('php artisan test --testsuite=MyTestsuite')
```

if somebody finds a other solution please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To call artisan in command you need to use next construction:

```
$this->call('test', ['test suite' => 'MyTestsuite']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Artisan` facade like the below:

```
    Artisan::call('test --testsuite=myTestsuite'); 
    $output = Artisan::output();
```